# How to address Zlib data stream format error when generating hoogle database?

Tags: macos, haskell, zlib

I am trying to generate a local hoogle database for its eventual use in a Haskell LSP with neovim.

Currently I'm running MacOS Monterey (12.6). I installed hoogle version 5.10.18.3 via cabal.

When running `hoogle generate` I get the following message:

```
$ hoogle generate
Starting generate
Reading Cabal... hoogle: Codec.Compression.Zlib: compressed data stream format error (incorrect header check)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to proceed? Typing `hoogle --help` or `hoogle generate --help` does not give much information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `hoogle generate --download`.

You probably had a corrupted download somehow. When hoogle attempts to re-generate the database it does not by default download. [Hoogle documentation](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle/blob/master/docs/Install.md)

> Index all of Stackage
>
> Run hoogle generate to generate an index for the current version of Stackage LTS. This command downloads the necessary inputs from the web as required and caches them (in the same directory as the database). To force redownloading pass `--download`. To demand no downloading, failing if the data cannot be found, pass `--download=no`. Links to the results will point at Hackage.

When I ran the `--download` flag, these files were fetched:

```
Downloading https://www.stackage.org/nightly/cabal.config... 1.81s
Downloading https://www.stackage.org/lts/cabal.config... 0.75s
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/haskell/haskell-platform/master/hptool/src/Releases2015.hs... 1.34s
Downloading https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/index.tar.gz... 3.67s
Downloading https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/hoogle.tar.gz... 6.89s
```